# xpath 1.0 distinct items

Tags: xml, xpath

Using xpath 1.0

I have the following xpath

```
/root/Locale/Client[@id=1234]/Category/Category/Category
```

Its a large xml doc.

Each category looks like this:

```
<Category 
    id="7211" 
    parentID="5103" 
    level="4" 
    creatorID="1" 
    sortOrder="2" 
    createDate="2014-09-12T09:19:17" 
    updateDate="2016-03-30T13:42:01" 
    nodeName="All" 
    urlName="all" 
    path="-1,1719,3292,5103,7211" 
    isDoc="" 
    nodeType="1071" 
    creatorName="Suhel Ahmed" 
    writerName="Suhel Ahmed" 
    writerID="1" 
    template="0" 
    nodeTypeAlias="Category">
```

Basically I need to select distinct categories at the 3rd level of categories where the distinct-ness is based on the nodeName.

I know in xpath 2.0 we have distinct-values but not in xpath 1.  Is there a way I can do this with xpath 1.0

wing

Comment: By *3rd level* do you mean *where attribute `level` equals `3`?

Comment: What do you want to return exactly, is it list of distinct `nodeName` attributes or  list`Category` elements? If it is the latter, then what should be returned when there are multiple `Category` elements with the same `nodeName` attribute value?

Comment: Actually the xpath above gets to the right level but the actual attribute level at that depth is 6.  We could use descendants and {@level=6]

Comment: I want to return a set of category nodes which have distinct nodeName

Comment: I guess the first unique category could be returned

Comment: You could've remove unrelated attributes from your sample XML (everything other than `level` and `nodeName` I guess), because they are not relevant to the question, and include more `Category` elements variant. Then post what should be selected by the XPath given that sample XML. Hopefully, that will make the question clear and ready to be answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question is still not clear to me. So firstly, I'll assume you want to filter `@level=6` as mentioned in your comment.

Now, assuming that all `Category` elements to be checked for duplicate share the same parent, you could use `preceding-sibling` as shown below to return distinct `Category` elements. In case of duplicated `nodeName` attributes in the source XML, only the first `Category` element with that `nodeName` value will be returned :

```
//Category[@level='6' and not(@nodeName = preceding-sibling::Category[@level='6']/@nodeName)]
```

Else, if `Category` elements may not share the same parent, try using `preceding` axis to replace `preceding-sibling` :

```
//Category[@level='6' and not(@nodeName = preceding::Category[@level='6']/@nodeName)]
```

Comment: Awesome, your second assumption is correct.  Category nodes will not share the same parent.  Gonna try it out now.

Comment: Still a bit off as should have an 'and' but got it working now //Category[@level='5' and not(@nodeName = preceding::Category[@level='5']/@nodeName)]

Comment: Sure it was off! thanks for the correction. Though, it could've been avoided if I have sample XML to test the XPath against :(

Comment: Very much appreciated :)